# why are the term_id and term_taxonomy_id doesn't match on custom taxonomies, but are duplicates on categories

Tags: custom-taxonomy

In the wp_term_taxonomy table if I look at the category taxonomy, and then look at all its term_id and term_taxonomy_id, they are all identical. But when I look at the last 4, which are from my custom taxonomy, they don't match. What is a good explanation for this.

I am not allowed to add images yet since I am new, so, I am adding a link to the screen-shot. Thanks.

[Screen Shot](http://bit.ly/xP3YXM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `term_id` is a unique ID for the term.
2. `term_taxonomy_id` is a unique ID for the `term`+`taxonomy` pair.

A taxonomy consists of sometimes many terms, so basically the `term_taxonomy_id` links the `term_id` to the `taxonomy`.

All info on these can be found here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Taxonomy